# Recover database after WAMP uninstall

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have uninstalled Wampserver for Windows for some reason.
I have then installed the same version/build on a different folder.
I have copied OLD physical directory of MySQL database of my site to the newly installed one.
Now tables appear on phpMyAdmin or Navicat but cannot be viewed. These clients say the tables don't exist.
How can I make DB work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INNODB databases are not stored only in the `\data\database_name` folders. Only .frm files are stored there and they contain just data dictionary information for tables in the innodb database.

The actual data, plus other data dictionary information is stored in the `\data\ibdata1` file.

So to recover these INNODB database you also need that file from your backup.

So stop MySQL and copy that file, then restart MySQL, with luck it will get recovered assuming you stopped MySQL cleanly the last time you used WAMPServer.

If that does not work, try copying the

```
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
```

And any 
    mysql-bin.0000??

Files as well.

Comment: The file data\ibdata1 had been removed during uninstall.

Comment: Then I am afraid you are not going to recover those databases.

Comment: For future reference the WAMPServer forum as a document on how to **safely** [install a new version of WAMPServer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606).

Comment: This is the answer to my question.
http://superuser.com/questions/675445/mysql-innodb-lost-tables-but-files-exist